# Autosys jobs schedule with batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, autosys

We have tried to schedule the batch file with Autosys from windows server. batch file will call couple of batch scripts internally. Autosys is triggering batch but it is not capturing the failure case, it always shows the success condition on the job whether it success or failure.

Question is: "can we capture the failure case when the any batch script end with error in the batch file?".

Appreciate for your action on this.

Answer (score 0):

How would anyone know. You kept the problem secret.

See `exit /?`.

But you have to set it.

Comment: yes the batch file is working in correct manner, batch scripts will terminate using exit command when error occur while running but we need to see that job in failure status(red color)in autosys box when the batch script fails as of now  autosys job not showing in red color even if the batch script fails

Comment: could someone help me out in this issue, where do we set the exit codes for Autosys to show the job in red color on the autosys console through the batch files.